# Equilibrium constant and thermodynamic relationship

Tags: physical-chemistry

Why is Equilibrium constant (Ratio of rate constants) considered as a thermodynamic quantity whereas the rate constant as kinetic quantity. Moreover why is extent of reaction also a thermodynamic quantity.?
Please explain briefly as I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Well first think of thermodynamics as determining what a system **wants** to do, and kinetics as what the system is **allowed** to do.  The rate  constant gives how **fast** something will react (kinetic rate).  The thermodynamic equilibrium constant gives **how much** of something will react.  Kinetics are dictated by the movements of atoms, Thermodynamics is dictated by the changes in energy and entropy.

Comment: But how will you justify your statement
Thermodynamic equilibrium constant gives how much of something will react.
Moreover, what exactly is meant by  extent of reaction, and why  is it a thermodynamic entity?

Answer (score 1):

We have a simple relation between Gibbs free energy change and the equilibrium constant for a given reaction as:
delta G naught= -RTln(K)

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship between the equilibrium constant and the forward- and reverse kinetics reaction rate constants:  $$K=\frac{k_f}{k_r}$$This relationship can be derived directly by setting the rate of the forward reaction equal to the rate of the reverse reaction at equilibrium.  This determines the extent of the reaction.  You can also derive a relationship between the thermodynamic heat of reaction and the activation energies for the kinetic forward- and reverse reaction rate constants.

Comment: So, what exactly does thermodynamics tell about a chemical reaction (Whether feasible or not)?
I didn't get the extent of reaction part in your answer, could you please elaborate it more, as I have an interview.

Comment: If you know the initial concentrations of the reactants and the equilibrium constant, you can calculate the final concentrations of reactants and products.  This is what I called the extent of the reaction., and this is what thermodynamics tells you.  If you want to design a reactor to achieve a certain conversion of reactants to products, you need to know the kinetics so that you can determine the size of the reactor needed.

Comment: Okay so, does that mean that thermodynamics can only be applied to equilibrium reactions.?

Comment: Most people would say that thermodynamics can only be applied to equilibrium situations.  Most would not accept the concept of determining the thermodynamic functions S, U, G, A, H for states of a system that is not at equilibrium (i.e.,  is undergoing an irreversible change).  I'm not one of those people, and I am not alone.  In my judgement, it is valid to determine the thermodynamic functions locally within a system not at equilibrium, and then integrating to get the functions over the entire mass of material.

Comment: okay, a small doubt, difference between a thermodynamic variable and kinetic varible

Comment: A kinetic variable tells you how fast a reaction is taking place.  A thermodynamic variable does not address rates; for example, the equilibrium constant just tells you the state of your system at final equilibrium (when the net rates are all zero).